# Is it possible to set constraints for a VARCHAR column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, constraints, varchar

Is it possible to set constraints for VARCHAR columns in MySQL?

I would like to not permit more than one row of a specific value.

```
   ______________
  |    MyTable   |
   --------------
  | pk id   INT  |
  | name VARCHAR |
```

If I now inserted two rows with the same name, "peter", I would like to throw an error. So, the constraint should only check if there is already a "peter" stored. But multiple rows of other values have to work.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (1, "peter");
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (2, "peter"); // This should fail
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (3, "steven"); 
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (4, "steven"); // Shall succeed
```

Is it possible in some way in MySQL to check for specified values?

Comment: check (name <> 'peter') as a part of 'where' clause while inserting a row else use a cartisan product to check if it match exists the list.

Comment: is the same id for both stevens intended or a typo?

Comment: ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD UNIQUE INDEX `name` (`name`);

Comment: @oezi: Sorry, my fault. I corrected it.

Comment: @TheJumpingFrog: Cool! So then "peter" will be unique for that column but not "steven"? (I have not the possibility to test that yet).

Comment: If you only need `peter`, just set a constraint on particular name. I suggested you to have a unique name only.

Comment: If 'peter' should fail but 'steven' should succeed, a unique index won't help - do this in your application, or use a database trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, thats not possible using constraints. you could add an [unique constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/constraint-primary-key.html) on `name`, but that would prevend all duplicate entrys, not just "peter". with that said, you'll have to do this additional check on your own.

Comment: [Here is that link in english.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/constraint-primary-key.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set the column to be UNIQUE. MySQL querys trying to insert a duplicate value will fail.

INSERT:
`insert into <table> (<columns>,unique(<unique column>));`

UPDATE:
`alter table <table> add unique(<unique column>));`

Comment: Yes, but that would make all entries unique for that column. I just want to make one value unique. In my example above, I just want to make "peter" unique but not "steven".

Comment: Oh, you want to just lock `Peter` to not be duplicate but allow multiple `Steve` entries?

Comment: Exactly! But maybe that´s not possible as oezi said :-)

Comment: No, it's not. Use programming language for that kind of restrictions.